# Sending base64 information using sockets

Tags: java, python, sockets, base64

I have been working with a server on python and a client on java. I have sent a picture from the client in java to the server in python, and encoded it to base64 and saved it in blob format in sql table. My question is: how do I get the whole code from java? What I do currently does not work.

This is how I save the picture in python :

```
with open("test.png", "rb") as f:
   data1 = f.read()
   data1.encode("base64")
   name1="Michael"# this is the user
with con:
      cur = con.cursor()
      cur.execute("INSERT INTO Pictures VALUES (%s, %s )",(name1, data1))
```

This is how I sent the picture:

```
   cur.execute("SELECT Pictures FROM Pictures where Users=%s",(name))#this is getting the encoded info
   rows=cur.fetchall()
   row_exist = int(cur.rowcount)
   if row_exist!=0:
     for row in rows:
         img=row["Pictures"]
         img.decode('base64')
         clientsock.send("About to send image\n")
         clientsock.sendall(img)
         clientsock.send("Something\n")
```

The code in the client : (java) :

```
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
    FileOutputStream writer= new FileOutputStream("/home/michael/Pictures/Somepic.png");
    while ((servMes=in.readLine())!=null)
    { 

     if (servMes.equals("About to send image"))


     { 
         System.out.println("entered");


     }}
```

What should I write in Java so the picture is sent? I am not really sure how can I come up with a proper buffer for the base64 type of information.I have tried to work something out with the string "Something" but my I couldn't.

I know I have posted similar question before but I have never gotten a proper answer.
(If you could also add in the converting to image file in Java I will be very thankful)

Comment: `"/home/michael/Pictures/Someshit.jpg"` - I can't imagine why you didn't get a proper response last time ^ ^.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: That's a perfectly valid name for a picture. Naming it differently does not affect the question at all. But surely he can change it to `somekittens.jpg` if that helps in any way.

Comment: openCV encodes pictures as matrices, and has APIs in both Java and Python.

Comment: Haha wow sorry I have not noticed.

Comment: boardrider - can you give me at least some basic code to work with?